# Vertically align text to the top

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment

I have some issue with latex. My content is vertically aligned to the middle. How can I change it

my contents starts like

```
\onecolumn
\begin{table}
\caption{Topics found by LDA}
\label{table:topics}
\small
\begin{tabular}{|p{4cm}|p{4cm}|p{4cm}|p{4cm}|}
\hline
\hline
\textbf{Title} & \textbf{Title} & \textbf{Title} & \textbf{Title} \tabularnewline 
\hline
```

[image]

As you can see it's vertically aligned to the middle, how can I change it to top.

Comment: @Mico. I have added some details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `table` is placed on a page with some other text, it should be possible to place it at the top of the page block by starting it off as follows:

```
\begin{table}[t!]
```

If, on the other hand, the `table` is on a floats-only page -- which is, by definition, the case if it's the *only* item on the page -- your options depend on which document class is in use. Assuming it's one of the "standard" LaTeX document classes (`article`, `report`, or `book`) or a class that's based on one of these classes, you can achieve your objective by inserting the following lines of code in the preamble:

```
\makeatletter
\setlength{\@fptop}{0\p@}   % top-alignment
\setlength{\@fpbot}{0\p@ \@plus 1fil}
\makeatother
```