# How to make the table be put at the top of the new page? (I use the \begin{table}[!t] but not work)

Tags: tables

when it happens that I write the end of the page and then I insert a table, the table appears in the next page will not be put in the top of the page as I desired but be put in the middle of the new page. I try to use

> \begin{table}[!t]

and

> \begin{table}[!ht]

but it didn't work. How to make at be put in the middle of the new page when changing pages? Thanks for and help!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please tell us more about the`table` in question. In particular, is it the case that it's the only object on the page? Also, do please tell us which document class you employ?

Comment: Do the posting [Vertically align text to the top](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/172679/5001) and [associated answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/172714/5001) address your formatting issue?

Comment: @Mico I think the OP is looking for this that you might recognise:-) https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28556/how-to-place-a-float-at-the-top-of-a-floats-only-page/28565#28565

Comment: Thanks for your help! I found the answer in the link that you provided:-)@Mico @DavidCarlisle